# select a class inside a div jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div with some span elements inside that when I click one it turns on and all the others turn off.  It works the first time ie turn on but I can't turn off, it also selects all the spans with the same id.  I am pretty new to Jquery and struggling!!  any pointers much appreciated

thanks Techboy

```
<div id="btn-grp">
        <span class="button ButtonOn">button1</span> 
        <span class="button ButtonOff">button2</span>
        <span class="button ButtonOff">button3</span>
        <span class="button ButtonOff">button4</span>
        <span class="button ButtonOff">button5</span>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#btn-grp").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('ButtonOn').siblings().removeClass('ButtonOff');
    }); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a div with some span elements inside that when I click one it turns on and all the others turn off.

Sounds like you want to add the `ButtonOn` class to the clicked element and remove it from the element which previously had it. Similarly, you want to removethe `ButtonOff` class from the clicked element and add it to previously "selected" element.

Your current code doesn't do this at all. It adds the `ButtonOn` class to the clicked element and removes the `ButtonOff` class from its siblings. You are never removing the `ButtonOn` class from any element. Furthermore, you bound the event handler to the *parent* of the elements. So you are actually applying the classes to the parent and the styles probably cascade down so that you get an unexpected behavior.

---

So, you have to add and remove both classes and bind the event handler to the right elements:

```
$("#btn-grp span.button").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.ButtonOn').add(this).toggleClass('ButtonOn ButtonOff');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/METw2/)

Depending how you want to treat clicks on an already "on" span, you might have to treat the previous element and the current element separately:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('ButtonOn').addClass('ButtonOff');
$(this).addClass('ButtonOn').removeClass('ButtonOff');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/METw2/1/)

FWIW, I would not use two classes to indicated the state of a button. I would just use one class to mark a button as "on" and have all others be styled as "off" by default.

Comment: yes but if I have five buttons only one can be on at any one time.

Comment: @user2247671: So? What are you trying to say with that? Why would my solution not work in this case?

Comment: Thats great new to Jquery and I would have never got that, I need to study it a bit and it shows my limited jquery knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

The selector you use is not very useful for this purpose since it adds a click handler to the button group, not the buttons itself, use 
`$(".button").click(...` instead.

Then all buttons have a click-handler and the button you click gets the ButtonOn-class while all siblings will get the ButtonOff.

Answer (score 1):

Make all your buttons `OFF` colored by default (means don't use the `.ButtonOff` at all):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/eyojen/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
<div id="btn-grp">
    <span class="button ButtonOn">button1</span> 
    <span class="button">button2</span>
    <span class="button">button3</span>
    <span class="button">button4</span>
    <span class="button">button5</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.button{
  cursor:pointer;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:4px 14px;
  margin:4px;
  display:inline-block;
  background:#ddd;
}

.ButtonOn{
  background:#cf5;
}
```

than just do:

```
$("#btn-grp .button").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('ButtonOn').siblings().removeClass('ButtonOn');
});
```